# MongoDB indexOnly false

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have created an index for the category field, then execute a find for {category: 'Example'} with the field selection like {_id: 0, category: 1}. Running explain on this query shows indexOnly to be false. It's really slow. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**
Explain:

```
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor title",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 2642,
        "nscannedObjects" : 2642,
        "nscanned" : 2642,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2642,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 2642,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 3,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "category" : [
                        [
                                "TV",
                                "TV"
                        ]
                ],
                "title" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "DeathDesk:27017"
}
```

**EDIT 2**
getIndexes()

```
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.media",
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "category" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.media",
                "name" : "category",
                "dropDups" : false,
                "background" : false
        }
]
```

Comment: Has the new `category` index finished building?

Comment: Can you include the explain results here as well?

Comment: @Stennie addex explain and yeah, indices should be finished. Is there a way to check?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `db.<collname>.getIndexes()` ?

Comment: The `explain` output indicates that the query used the `title` index which looks like it includes both the `title` and `category` fields (but isn't listed in your `getIndexes` output which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Re-creation of collection and index fixed the issue.. moving to vote for a close.

Comment: Don't slap it as an answer and accept it so we learn for the next time this happens, there must have been index corruption